# 'English' global variables don't work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rubygems, global-variables

I'm trying to use the English gem in Rails, so I can access `$LAST_MATCH_INFO`, the less cryptic version of `$~`. However, despite requiring English, `$LAST_MATCH_INFO` is always `nil`, while `$~` still works.

This is my expected behaviour from `irb`:

```
'foo' =~ /o/           # => 1
$~                     # => #<MatchData "o">
$LAST_MATCH_INFO       # => nil

require 'english'      # => true
$LAST_MATCH_INFO       # => #<MatchData "o">
$LAST_MATCH_INFO == $~ # => true
```

This is the broken behaviour from `rails console`:

```
'foo' =~ /o/           # => 1
$~                     # => #<MatchData "o">
$LAST_MATCH_INFO       # => nil

require 'english'      # => false
                       # (Means it's already been required)
$LAST_MATCH_INFO       # => nil
$LAST_MATCH_INFO == $~ # => false
```

It works in `irb`, but not in `rails console`, or in the web console.  Notice that `require 'english'` returns `false` because the gem is already loaded, and yet it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR: Removed the `gem 'english'` from Gemfile, works.**

I ended up coming back to this months later and figuring it out.

In my hastiness to use the [`English` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html), I added the [`english` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/english/) to my `Gemfile`. (Notice the capitalization).

While `English` is the built in library I wanted, for descriptive global variables, `english` is a gem for general english language processing.

Normally, `require 'english'` would require the gem, and `require 'English'` would require the library.  However, I am using a *case insensitive* Mac OS X system, so `require 'English'` found the `english` gem first and used that.  This meant it was impossible for Ruby to load the `English` library, which is why it never worked.